# Cakephp 3.5 query - Filter entries with same title

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm using CakePhp 3.5 for a project i'm working on. My problem is about building a query. I have a growing database with `id`, `title`, `content`, `user_id` and a few, in this case not really interesting fields.

The software is about event management, so entries with the same title could (and probably will) be identical in every field but not in for example date or time. But my only concern in this situation is about title.

I'm doing an autocomplete function to offer the user the possibility to fill the add form via Ajax with data from a previous made entry.

So i'm searching as the user inputs a title, older entries with similar titles.

As doubling titles is totally ok i'm getting a bunch of result as it should be. But i only need to get one result per unique Title, i.e. if there are 5 Entries with the title "**Party**" i only want to get 1 of them.
But if there are also events with the titles "**Party at McDonalds**" and "**Partybus planning**" i want to get a list with:

- "Party"
- "Party at McDonalds"
- "Partybus planning"

where one entry for every relevant title is shown.

Different content doesn't bother me. If my Users set identical titles for different contents it's their own problem. They have to learn how to use the title so the could work with the software.

I'm looking for some sort of condition or selector which tells cake to only fetch one entry per identical title. Doing this in php would cause leaks in the software on the long run, which for this project is planned.

my current query looks like this:

```
$events_query = $this->Events
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'title LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->data('title') . '%'
    ])
    ->andwhere([
        'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    ]);
```

Does anyone have a solution for my problem? I'm kind of stuck so perhaps someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `group` the title with the group()-Function of the query-builder

See here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having

Comment: `distinct` would also work, documentation on the same page. Not sure which would be faster, you could do some tests. If you wanted to also get the count of records that have that title, to sort by the most common in the selection for example, then `group` is definitely the way to go.